# about deepClone

Tags: java

When I run the code below, why does it throw this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: Student
    at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)
    at Student.clone(Student.java:44)
    at StudentApp.main(StudentApp.java:10)
```

Here's my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {

    Address address = new Address("湖南省长沙市林科大","1234567",20);
    Student stu = new Student("诸葛亮量",20);
    stu.setAddress(address);

    Student stu2 = (Student)stu.clone();
    stu2.setAddress(new Address("湖南省常德市区","484848348",22));

    stu2.setName("张飞飞");
    stu2.setAge(23);
    stu.sayHi();
    stu2.sayHi();
}
```

This is Student class:

```
public class Student{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("大家好，我是" + this.getName() + "同学，我今年" + this.getAge()
                + "岁了……我的HashCode是：" + this.hashCode()+"。我家庭住址是"+address.getAddress()+"，家庭住址的HashCode为："+address.hashCode());
    }

}
```

This is Address Class:

```
public class Address {

    private String address;
    private String tel;
    private int roadNum;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public int getRoadNum() {
        return roadNum;
    }

    public void setRoadNum(int roadNum) {
        this.roadNum = roadNum;
    }

    public Address() {
        super();
    }

    public Address(String address, String tel, int roadNum) {
        super();
        this.address = address;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.roadNum = roadNum;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)

> Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement
>   the Cloneable interface results in the exception
>   CloneNotSupportedException being thrown.

Have you tried to make your `Student` class implement the Cloneable interface?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attempting to use `clone()`, write a copy constructor that takes an instance of a  Student and copies it's fields individually.  Then you don't need to worry about the semantics of `clone`.  In your example, this means having a copy constructor on Address as well, since a student has an Address field.

Read [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) by Joshua Bloch for reasons why clone should be avoided.

```
public class Student {

    final private String name;
    final private int age;
    final private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public Student(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student(Student copyStudent) {
        this.name = new String(copyStudent.getName());
        this.age = copyStudent.getAge();
        this.address = new Address(copyStudent.getAddress());
    }
}
```

From Effective Java

> The copy constructor approach and its static factory variant have many
>   advantages over  Cloneable/clone: They do not rely on a risk-prone
>   extralinguistic object creation mechanism; they do not demand
>   unenforceable adherence to ill-documented conventions; they do not
>   conflict with the proper use of final fields; they do not require the
>   client to catch an unnecessary checked exception; and they provide a
>   statically typed object to the client. While it is impossible to put a
>   copy constructor or static factory in an interface, Cloneable fails to
>   function as an interface because it lacks a public clone method.
>   Therefore you aren’t giving up interface functionality by using a copy
>   constructor instead of a clone method. Furthermore, a copy constructor
>   (or static factory) can take an argument whose type is an appropriate
>   interface implemented by the class. For example, all general-purpose
>   collection implementations, by convention, provide a copy constructor
>   whose argument is of type Collection or Map. Interface-based copy
>   constructors allow the client to choose the implementation of the
>   copy, rather than forcing the client to accept the implementation of
>   the original. For example, suppose you have a LinkedList l, and you
>   want to copy it as an  ArrayList. The clone method does not offer this
>   functionality, but it’s easy with a copy constructor: new
>   ArrayList(l). Given all of the problems associated with  Cloneable, it
>   is safe to say that other interfaces should not extend it and that
>   classes designed for inheritance (Item 15) should not implement it.
>   Because of its many shortcomings, some expert programmers simply
>   choose never to override the clone method and never to invoke it
>   except, perhaps, to copy arrays cheaply. Be aware that if you do not
>   at least provide a well-behaved  protected clone method on a class
>   designed for inheritance, it will be impossible for subclasses to
>   implement Cloneable.

Comment: Hi, http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm read this. And edit your answer :)

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your post to provide you more reasons why you shouldn't use clone.

Comment: Because copy constructor has it flaws too. This article is much better then that 1 chapter inside Effective Java. So if you recommend CC over copy(), because copy() disadvantages, you should aim for private or protected CC, not public

Answer (score 1):

Student needs to implement Cloneable.

Answer (score 0):

Student and Address both need 'deep' clone, if you don't want to share Address instance both in source and target Student instances:

```
class Student implements Cloneable {
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Student result = (Student)super.clone();
        result.setAddress((Address)getAddress().clone());
        return result;       
    }
...
}

class Address implements Cloneable{
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return  (Address) super.clone();
    }
...
}
```